# Подсчет количества повторений элемента

Tags: postgresql, sql

У меня есть табличка. В ней есть поле `city`. Там могут быть неуникальные записи.

Как мне составить рейтинг городов? То есть я хочу посчитать количество одинаковых городов, и отсортировать их.

Вся загвоздка в подсчете количества вхождений каждого города. Никак не могу понять, как это сделать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

как-то так

```
select count(первичный_ключ) as city_count from таблица_с_городами group by city order by city_count desc;
```

Comment: Вроде все тоже делаю, но эффект - записи выводятся по одной с количеством 1.

Comment: Это что, последовательность единичек? (Других полей там вроде нет).
`select city, count(*) as city_count from tbl group by city order by city_count desc;`

Comment: Перед `from` надо добавить `, city `. Тогда будет с названием города.

Comment: Идея в том, что надо было добавить обработку данных ф-ей `Trim`. Оказалось, что название города добавлялось с пробелами.